# StackEmptyException occuring when not expected

Tags: java, stack

I have this part of a class

```
private static Stack<Integer> integers = new Stack<Integer>();

private static int nextInt()
{               
    if(integers.isEmpty())
    {
        refill();
    }

    return integers.pop();
}

public static int peekInt()
{
    if(integers.isEmpty())
    {
        refill();
    }

    return integers.peek();
}

private static synchronized void refill()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<7; i++)
        integers.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(integers);
}
```

and two different threads call the methods nextInt and peekInt but sometimes they get a stack empty exception but why would that happen if they both call refill before getting their value.

here is the exception trace

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at Utility.peekInt(Utility.java:26)
at Frame$repainter.run(Frame.java:72)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Because a thread may be trying to peek the stack while the other thread has cleared the stack. All your methods must be synchronized. Another advice, it would be better that the stack wasn't `static`.

Comment: but how would i synchronize two methods together also if stack wasn't static then i would have to create an instance of my class

Comment: By the way, `Stack` extends from `Vector` which is not really meant to be used. It would be better to use [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implemented by [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not thread safe. Consider the scenario where the stack contains only one element/integer, and two threads are executing in the nextInt() and peekInt() methods, both will see the stack is non empty and therefore refill() method is not called, now if one thread executes pop() slightly before the other thread calls peek(), you will get the StackEmptyException.

Synchronizing nextInt() and peekInt() will solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Because it isn't thread-safe. Suppose the stack has one element in it and both threads are at the statement `if(integers.isEmpty())`, which both would return false and step over to the next statement. Now if the thread that invokes `nextInt()` goes first and calls `integers.pop()`, then the one element will be taken from the stack and the stack will be empty. Now when the other thread that invokes `peekInt()` executes `integers.peek()`, it will throw `EmptyStackException` since there are no elements in the stack.

What you can do is trying to synchronize the methods `nextInt()` and `peekInt()` beside synchronizing `refill()`, as follows:

```
private static synchronized int nextInt(){...}
```

```
public static synchronized int peekInt(){...}
```